# Inequality in a triangle: $BC > \frac 12AB$ if $∠A > ∠B$ (self-answered)

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $∠A > ∠B$, prove that:
  $BC > \frac 12AB$

Comment: When I was reading help content regarding useful activities , somebody had told we can publish our experience to public to be useful for(probably novice) other people! This act was not my Idea! If you  people dislike it so badly,I delete it....

Comment: Indeed. In fact the system suggests you answer your own question. It's a way of initiating dialogue.

Comment: So why 5 people marked my question as off-topic???!!!

Comment: I do not mind. This site do allow (and encourage) people to answer their own questions. However by posting the answer right after the question I think you will find that not many people will contribute to it (why answer when OP has already solved it). If I were you I would wait a bit and let other people have a go first, but that is up to you. The reason the question was closed is that it has no context, read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for how to write a good question on this site.

Comment: Thank you for guidance.I thought selecting a tag is sufficient for specifying context. Is it possible to delete that question or somehow activate it?

Comment: @Hamid I think that mentioning that you have self-answered your question counts as adding context. If you edit this into the question, it is better chance that the users will notice that it is self-answered. I will also add a link to [related discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21552/closed-as-off-topic-after-asking-and-answering-own-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $∠A > ∠B$ then $BC>CA$ . Using the triangle inequality we obtain $AB<BC+CA$ and by the previous statement, $AB<2BC$ which gives:  $BC > \frac 12AB$.